# What's the best way to use pattern matching in F#?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, tuples, inline

Make a function that takes two arguments, an integer and a five element tuple of integers that returns true if the sum of any three elements of the tuple is greater than the first argument, else false.

```
let func el tupl =
    match tupl with
    |(a,b,c,d,e) when (a+b+c) > el || (a+d+e) > el || (b+c+d)> el || (b+c+e) > el -> true
    | _-> false
```

Comment: Can you not just turn the 5 tuple into an array, sort it, and check the sum of the last three numbers in the array?

Comment: can you show me how... I am still a kid in F#

Comment: Also you forgot `a+b+d` and `a+b+e`...

Comment: In general, if the different elements don't each have a distinct meaning, don't use tuples but lists or arrays. Tuples aren't collections and hard to work with if used as such.

Comment: #TeaDrivenDev Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't really an advantage to using an explicit `match` expression in this case, you can solve the problem using `when` guards as you suggested in your question but it transfers a lot of the thinking burden to you.

Here is an alternative:

```
let inline func el (a,b,c,d,e) =
    let sum3 = 
        [a; b; c; d; e] // create a list of elements
        |> List.sortDescending // sort list by descending
        |> List.take 3 // take the 3 largest elements
        |> List.sum // sum them
    sum3 > el // if not true for 3 largest, it's not true for any
```

Note: I made the function `inline` so it would work with any type that supports `comparison` and `+`.  You could remove the `inline` and just accept, for example `int`s.